# Find a line which starts with a term and delete it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to automatically truncate a long conversation between two people which has been pasted into word.

**Input**

```
Jim , 18th November 05:23

Hi!

Sarah , 19th November 06:03

Hello there
```

I want to format all text from Jim blue, and all text from Sarah red. In order to do this I think I need to follow this process:

1. Colour every bit of text red
2. Find a line starting with "Jim ," and format everything after it blue until it reaches a line which starts with "Sarah ,".

Comment: Do you have to use VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
Public Sub ColorMeRedBlue()
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    color_the_text = False

    For Each line_in_para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

        text_in_line = line_in_para.Range.Text
        check_name = Split(text_in_line, " ")

        If InStr("Jim", check_name(0)) Then
            color_the_text = False
        ElseIf InStr("Sarah", check_name(0)) Then
            color_the_text = True
        End If

        If color_the_text = False Then
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.Font.Color = wdColorRed
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
        ElseIf color_the_text = True Then
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.Font.Color = wdColorBlue
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
        End If

    Next line_in_para

End Sub
```